# Laravel 5.4 upgrade broke API Dingo tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.4, dingo-api

I use Laravel 5.3 with Dingo to manage the API requests. I am trying to upgrade to Laravel 5.4 but my tests are failing.

Here is a case:

```
$request = $this->get('/api/authenticated-user', $this->headers());
$limit = $request->response->headers->get("X-RateLimit-Limit");
$times = $request->response->headers->get("X-RateLimit-Remaining") - 1;
do {
    $request = $this->get('/api/authenticated-user', $this->headers());
    $request->seeHeader("X-RateLimit-Limit", $limit);
    $request->seeHeader("X-RateLimit-Remaining", $times);
    $request->seeStatusCode(($times == 0 ? 429 : 200));
    $times--;
} while ($times > 0);
```

Before upgrade it worked like a charm, but now it is returning:

```
Undefined property: Dingo\Api\Http\Response::$response
```

This error happens in the second line. If I remove `response` it works:

```
$limit = $request->headers->get("X-RateLimit-Limit");
```

However the following line fails:

```
$request->seeHeader("X-RateLimit-Limit", $limit);
```

In this case `seeHeader`is not defined.

I changed composer from `"dingo/api": "1.0.*@dev"` to `"dingo/api": "v1.0.0-beta8"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realise the "problem" is in Laravel not in Dingo. The error message misguided me.

Laravel 5.4 has a new testing layer, in order to provide compatibility there is a package. Laravel upgrade guide has all the information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade in Testing section.